# Crontab node.js/socket.io

Tags: linux, socket.io, cron

Sometimes my socket.io server crashes. Until I find a solution I want to automatically restart it. Is it possible to create a crontab or something (linux) which checks every 10 seconds if the server is still running and if not starts it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just start it with a loop from the shell: while true; do socket.io; done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it will be easier to just use [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

```
$ [sudo] npm install forever -g
```

you may have to daemonize it though... google according to your OS.